# ASP.NET Membership: "Attribute not recognized 'hashAlgorithmType'" (SHA256)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I want to use SHA256 as the hashalgorithmtype in my Membership Provider instead of the default SHA1.

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" hashAlgorithmType="SHA256">
<providers>
   passwordFormat="Hashed"
   hashAlgorithmType="SHA256"/>
</providers>
```

This gives me the following error when I want to save to the Membership table:
*"Attribute not recognized 'hashAlgorithmType'"*

Is there any way to solve this? Can't seem to find anything on the net...

Comment: Your XML looks wrong. You've got a close tag (/>) after your algorithm type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should look like this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" hashAlgorithmType="yourAlgorithmType">
<providers>
   <!-- optional provider information here. just leave empty if you wish -->
</providers>
```